# display: inline; makes li background image disappear

Tags: html, css

So I used the example given by by w3schools to create a div with a list in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/TBsx8/

```
#links li {
        height: 32px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        list-style: none;
}
```

is the relevant part.

You can see that everything works fine (I took a random twitter icon for all of them in this example)

Problem is, I want them inline. So, I change it to `display: inline;`. no problem, right? nope, it makes eveything disappear. `inline-block` does not do anything either. any solutions?

Edit: sorry, did not make this clear: I want the links horizontally.

Comment: why would you want them inline? If you have them as inline then because they have no content in them they will be 0px x 0px and will disppear. They show up fine as `display: inline-block`

Comment: As a general rule, don't use w3schools to learn anything.

Comment: Use `inline-block` with fixed width ie. `32px`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you want them horizontally and inline? Can you show an example of this working in the wild so that we can help you please?

Comment: @marflar http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm example is at the very top of the page. Seeing as I am at -1 votes, how can I improve this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inline-block` works just fine. You've got your wrapper `DIV` fixed to `4em` in height though. So it gets cutoff:

Fiddle with `inline-block` and fixed height commented out:

http://jsfiddle.net/TBsx8/2/

For horizontal layout set `width` of `LIs`: (`width:100%` causes the LI to consume all horizontal space available)

```
#links li {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;      /*  <<-----  */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TBsx8/8/

Comment: I did not make this so clar, but I want the images horizontal

Comment: this works, but I did not notice that these are not links tight now :/ EDIT: fixed by putting the <li> into <a> instead of the other way.

Comment: Here's an article that addresses the spacing: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ You may need to go with `float:left`

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left` and `width:32px`, this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width to 32px and display to inline-block and it should work. Right now you have the width at 100% which will fill in container.

Answer (score 0):

the width of your li's should not be 100%, try an exact width.

code block using 20% width that works:

```
#links li {
    height: 32px;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As an adjunct to the calls for you to use `display:inline-block;width:32px`, it's worth saying that the reason for this is that you can't apply a width to any element that is displayed inline. Ever.

Alternatively you could use `display:block;width:32px;float:left` on the `li`, and `overflow:hidden` or a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the containing `ul/ol/dl` to prevent the margins from collapsing due to the floats

Comment: `display:block` would be redundant when using `float:left`

Comment: @KevinBoucher how come? I'm not sure I understand. Is it because `li` tags are block by default?

Comment: Setting it to `float:left` causes it to be `display:block`. Works on any element.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot, I didn't know that. Good to know this sort of thing.